# Scanner nextline() excution failure

Tags: java.util.scanner

I want to stop the excution of the program after the first nextline() call, however it's printing after the nextLine() call instead of stopping.

```
if(j==1){
                    System.out.println("Enter Book Title");
                    String bTitle = inputs.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Enter Book Reference");
                    String bRef = inputs.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Enter Book Price");
}
```

Output:

Enter Book Title

Enter Book Reference

Answer (score 0):

I tried out the given code and its doing as expected. Did you want an input  after the last print out statement? If so, just call nextInt() after the last print out statement and assign the int to a variable.